# How can I create a Bash conditional script, based on output from a command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, files, for

I have a Java program that gets two arguments (a video file name and an image) and outputs a boolean (0 or 1) in the first line:

```
java -jar myProgram video1.mp4 image.png
> 0
>some extra information...
>other extra information....going on
```

Now using bash script, I need to iterate through all files in a folder (not files in nested folders), run the program with the file name passed to the first argument (video name changes everytime, and image is fixed), and if the output in the first line is 0, copy the file in `folder0`, and if the output is 1, copy the file to `folder1`.

How can I achieve that in bash?

Comment: Are the `>` signs part of the output?

Comment: oh no. Just to show it is output!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have much better control when using conditional statements:

```
for file in *; do
   if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
      output=$(java -jar myProgram "$file" image.png | head -n 1)
      [[ $output = "0" ]] && cp -- "$file" folder0
      [[ $output = "1" ]] && cp -- "$file" folder1
   fi
done
```

**EDIT:** if you still want to see the output of `java`, you can use this:

```
output=$(java -jar myProgram "$file" image.png | tee /dev/tty | head -n 1)
```

Comment: I only changed the `0` and `1` to `false` and `true`, but I get error:

Comment: `runme.sh: line 4: conditional binary operator expected
runme.sh: line 4: syntax error near `"true"'
runme.sh: line 4: `      [[ $output= "true" ]] && cp -- "$file" video'`

Comment: Even with the original 0 and 1 id shows the same error.

Comment: @TinaJ There has to be the space before `=`. So it should be `$output = 1`.

Comment: What if I only need to get .mp4 files in the current directory?

Comment: @TinaJ Please, read on filename expansion in `bash`, `for file in *.mp4`...

Comment: Please update your answer for the ` =` space.

Comment: @TinaJ Ugh, I changed the names of variables for better readability and accidentally deleted the spaces :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
for f in source/*
do
    cp "$f" folder$(java -jar myProgram "$f" image.png | head -1)
done
```

Comment: Where is the condition then?

Comment: What condition? You said that the program returns 0 or 1 and that you want to copy to folder0 in first case and folder1 in second case, so the result value (0 or 1) is just appended to string "folder" to create the folder name as folder0 or folder1.

Comment: oh I see. Tnx. It works. What if I only need to get .mp4 files in the *current* directory?

Comment: Replace `source/*` by `current/*.mp4`

Comment: Tnx. Works perfectly. Wondering why I don't see any outputs? I do `sh runme.sh`, but no outputs!

Comment: This is expected, the script just run the cp command to copy files and the java command output is captured inside the `$(...)` construct, there should be no output except if problems.

Comment: Interesting. Any ways I can still show the outputs for each run?

Comment: @TinaJ Yes, you can achieve that with `tee`. You can read about `tee` in [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html) and refer to my answer for solution.

Comment: Thanks. Both answers are great. I have a hard time selecting the answer. The other one was 5 min faster ;)